# Change variable type dynamicallly

Tags: c#, types

I have an argument in my function which is an object. I would like to change the type of this object in order to have access to the class methods (string, int ...).

I know the convert methods and casts. But I want to keep the same argument name. Like :

```
public void MyFunction(object test)
{
   SpecialConvertFunctionToString(test) // Now test is a string
   test.Contains(...)                   // I can use string methods on
}
```

I don't know if it's possible ! Thanks !

Comment: Use an interface... if you cant, well you might need to rethink your problem

Comment: No, you can't change the type of a variable. Why would you not want `string testAsString = SpecialConvertFunctionToString(test); bool contains = testAsString.Contains(...)` etc? This feels like an XY problem - what you've asked can't be done, but we don't know what problem you think it's a solution to in the first place. *Maybe* `dynamic` is the way forward for you, but we don't really know...

Comment: @user676767 Can you ask about this function that you are trying to write instead, providing details like how are you deciding what type the second argument is and what exactly is the function supposed to do? Right now, your question is a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't precised that I don't have a special problem, I was curious if it was possible or not. I have my answer now, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a cast `as` or `is` and then compare.

This will check if test is of type MyClass.  If it is, then it casts it as this type into the variable myclassobj.  Then you can use the methods, properties of MyClass as normal

```
if (test is MyClass myclassobj)
{
    myclassobj.Name = "new name";
    myclasssobj.ExecuteMyMethod();
    //etc
}
```